Laravel Breeze Error: No matching version found for @tanstack/virtual-core@3.10.0
I'm trying to make my first Laravel app with React on the front-end using Breeze. I followed the instructions and installed PHP and Composer. Now trying to set up the Laravel app according to the instructions here and here, I run the commands
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^11.0 app
cd app
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
php artisan breeze:install

wherein I am met with the following error from NPM
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @tanstack/virtual-core@3.10.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

I've narrowed down the issue as being part of the @headlessui/react dependency, but I'm completely stumped on what to do about it, other than just not using the library.

I just got this error on an existing node app as well that was fine a few hours ago. This isn't your problem. Still investigating.

Rolling back to a previous version is the way to go. I don't know anything about your laravel stack so hopefully one of the other comments can help you.

Rolling back to version 2.1.1 solved the issue for me. You can find more details in the official repository: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/3430

I ran into the same problem, I was able to work around it for my application to continue running however, I lowered the version of the @headlessui/react beneath 2.0.0 inside the devDependencies in the package.json and then ran npm install. Good luck!

What version is currently working for you?

Seems HeadlessUI is trying to access @tanstack/react-virtual@3.10.0 but 3.9.0 is the latest version. Adding this line to package.json is a viable workaround to use the latest version of HeadlessUI while the issue is being resolved
"overrides": {
    "@tanstack/react-virtual": "3.9.0"
}

https://github.com/TanStack/virtual/issues/804#issuecomment-2297407874
